# Candy Crush payment

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I have just finished level 335 on Candy Crush. The next level is apparently a quest asking for payment for me to progress to the next level. It doesn't give me the option to play 3 quests during 24 hours each. I have never seen anything like this before. What should I do? Also, I am not on Facebook if that matters.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197246/not-offered-candy-crush-quest-anymore