# Not offered Candy crush Quest anymore.

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I just completed level 135 candy crush and am not offered quest option. I am not logged into Facebook. Help!

Answer (score 4):

Go to setting. Turn airplane mode ON. Then the "play quests" option will automatically appear! Took me a solid hour to figure it out!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might have to completely go offline (no 3G or wifi), not just from Facebook.  Read the last entry of [the first post here](https://forums.king.com/en/forum/candy-crush-saga/discussions-ccs/the-kingdom#.VJUdlV4ALk) and see if that works.

The part of the post of interest:

> **What happened to my Mystery Quests?**
>
> You will now be able to ask your Kingdom co-players for tickets to progress in the game but if you are offline (not connected to 3G/wi-fi) then the Mystery Quests will still be available.
> I hope that you all enjoy this amazing new feature and if you have any further questions, please let me know.